# Programmatically create a commit containing Git-LFS data to a Github Repository

Tags: github, graphql, github-actions, github-api, git-lfs

*Ether by using the GraphQL (Preferred but seems unlikely), REST API, or by any other means.*

Ideally it would be possible to commit the LFS objects and regular objects in the same commit.

---

I have been using the GraphQL API to successfully query and download LFS objects. I was hoping that it would be possible to also create commits that contain LFS objects.

Unfortunately it seems like `createCommitOnBranch` doesn't provide a documented way of doing that. So I am left with looking for alternatives.

---

A version of this question is in the Github Community GraphQL category: https://github.community/t/create-a-commit-containing-lfs-data-via-graphql/252637